# Bash/ syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Tags: bash

I have the following code in `bash`:

```
check_port()
{
    local host=${1}
    local port=${2}
    echo $host
    echo $port
    while true; do
        if nc -w 5 -z 127.0.0.1 111 && nc -w 5 -z 127.0.0.1 5001 ;
        then
          echo -e "\a\n => Port at host is open"
          break
        else
          echo -e "\a\n => Port at host is closed"
          break
        fi
}
```

For some reason, I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `}'
`}'
```

I don't understand why: `}` is closing the scope of the function.

Comment: Looking up the syntax of the `while` loop would have taught you what is wrong with your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `done` line to terminate your `while` loop, between the `fi` line and the closing brace `}`.

However, I'm not entirely certain why you even *have* the `while true` loop since you break out of it regardless of whether the `if` evaluates to true or false. Hence it's superfluous, unless you plan on changing the behaviour of one of those blocks at some point.

If you're *not* planning that, you're better off with the much simpler:

```
check_port()
{
    local host=${1}
    local port=${2}
    echo $host
    echo $port
    if nc -w 5 -z 127.0.0.1 111 && nc -w 5 -z 127.0.0.1 5001 ; then
        echo -e "\a\n => Port at host is open"
    else
        echo -e "\a\n => Port at host is closed"
    fi
}
```

---

I'm also not entirely certain of the sanity of passing in the host and port and then ignoring them (instead using `localhost` with two hard-coded ports).

However, I'm going to assume that you're still in the development/testing phase rather than the possibility you've gone insane :-)

Comment: Sorry, I still in the development phase. I will use the break just if the condition return true. Also, I would take out the local host and port. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `done` at the end of the `while` loop is missing

```
      ....
      break
    fi
 done;
```

}